# How to get a separate form_id for each of the taxonomy/term/%term exposed form?

Tags: views

I'm trying to combine in a smart way `Contextual filters Has taxonomy term ID` with `Remember the last selection` feature of exposed form filters in a view.

### Context

- A taxonomy vocabulary called destinations (countries & regions)
- A view of content tagged with *destinations* terms : `Contextual filters : Content: Has taxonomy term ID (with depth)`
- Exposed filters such as travel duration, price...
- Important point, **Remember the last selection** is ticked for all the filters
- Ajax enabled, and the whole thing displayed as a content pane

### The issue

Let's say I visit `taxonomy/term/spain` and filter the view by *price < 700$*, then go to `taxonomy/term/india` e.g, the view will be already filtered by *price < 700$*, and may return empty result, which is an unwanted behaviour.

This is because across all the `taxonomy/term/%` paths, the exposed form form_id remains the same `views_exposed_form`.

How could I get a separate form_id for each of the `taxonomy/term/%` exposed form, so that the last selection would be kept for each term ?

Or setup my view in order to get the expected features ?

Comment: I don't think the remember property is stored by form id. I think it's stored against the view and display id.

Comment: Thanks. Could you develop "against the view and display id" please ?

Comment: I think you'll need to create a custom handler for the filter which stores the property differently by overriding the store_exposed_input() method.

Comment: This sounds exactly what I'm looking for. Is it too much asking you to post an answer with a general coding approach for _create a custom handler for the filter which stores the property differently by overriding the store_exposed_input() method_ ? I've never done such thing I'm afraid

Comment: It's quite a job unfortunately - looks like the settings is referenced all over the place in views, not just in the filter. Quite a lot of code, which I don't currently have time to write. Hopefully someone else will have a bright idea: probably would be best to turn off the views remember setting and create something separate.

Comment: Ok If this sounds like a big patch, I'll let that advanced feature for better days then...  Thank you anyway  for your help !

Comment: Good question, though, worth asking. Hopefully someone will answer eventually :)

Answer (score 2):

Without patching the module you can't...but the View object is always available in the form state, so you can use that to check where you are. e.g.

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form') {
    $view = $form_state['view'];
    if ($view->name == 'foo' && $view->current_display == 'bar') {
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Fine, thanks. But do you think I could just change the form_id into `hook_form_alter`  such as `views_exposed_form_%term` ... ? I'm afraid to face very unexpected things. I have no other idea to get it work as desired

Comment: It won't do anything, `$form_id` is a variable local only to that alter function. You can accept it by reference and change it, but the calling function isn't obligated to (and won't) respect that in any way. I'm not totally clear on what you're trying to do so I don't have a better suggestion, sorry

Comment: I want to keep a remembered selection per term view basis, not per global  `views_exposed_form`

Comment: Ok I see, you'll probably want to follow Alfred's advice in the comments and build your own handler for something like that. You could always keep your own context in the session and use that to alter the default value that's set on the form, but I'm not sure that would permeate through to the View query from a form alter